# Pointer class/handle

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers

Please review my pointer class.

```
template<typename T>
class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr(T* t, int s = 1) {
        sz = s;
        p = new T[sz];
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
            p[i] = t[i];
        }
    }

    Ptr(const Ptr&) = delete;
    Ptr& operator=(const Ptr&) = delete;

    Ptr(Ptr &&t) :p{t.p}, sz{t.sz} {
        t.p = nullptr;
        t.sz = 0;
    }

    Ptr& operator=(Ptr &&t) {
        std::swap(t.p,p);
        std::swap(t.sz,sz);
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*() {
        check_range();
        return *p;
    }

    T& operator[](int i) {
        check_range(i);
        return p[i];
    }

    Ptr& operator+=(int i) {
        check_range(index+i);
        index += i;
        p+= i;
        return *this;
    }

    Ptr& operator-=(int i) {
        check_range(index-i);
        index -= i;
        p -= i;
        return *this;
    }

    Ptr& operator+(int i) {
        Ptr old{*this};
        return old+=1;
    }

    Ptr& operator-(int i) {
        Ptr old{*this};
        return old-=1;
    }

    Ptr& operator++() {
        return operator+=(1);
    }

    Ptr operator++(int) {
        Ptr<T> old{p};
        operator++();
        return old;
    }

    Ptr& operator--() {
        return operator-=(1);
    }

    Ptr operator--(int) {
        Ptr<T> old{p};
        operator--();
        return old;
    }

    ~Ptr() {
        while (index < sz-1) {
            operator++();
        }
        while (index != 0) {
            delete p;
            operator--();
        }
        delete p;
    }

private:
    T* p;
    int sz;
    int index = 0;
    void check_range(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > sz-1) {
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        }
    }
    void check_range() {
        if (p == nullptr) {
            throw std::out_of_range("null pointer");
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It appears that some of your code has lost its indentation.

Comment: @Matthew Read
 I have re-pasted the code. Does it look fine now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only need to point out one thing.

Constructor:

```
    p = new T[sz];
```

Destructor:

```
    delete p;
```

This code is broken. If you allocation with `new []` you **MUST** destroy with `delete []`.

In the `operator+=` and `operator-=`

```
Ptr& operator+=(int i) {
    check_range(index+i);
    index += i;
    p+= i;
    return *this;
}

Ptr& operator-=(int i) {
    check_range(index-i);
    index -= i;
    p -= i;
    return *this;
}
```

Thus moving `p` during the lifetime of the object is not a good idea (because you must call delete on the pointer returned by new). So if you are going to move `p` you need to keep track of the original pointer in another member. But I would not move it all. You are adjusting `index` so why adjust `p`?

These can't return by reference:

```
Ptr& operator+(int i) {
    Ptr old{*this};
    return old+=1;
}

Ptr& operator-(int i) {
    Ptr old{*this};
    return old-=1;
}
```

You have to return by value because you are creating new values.

I am surprised that this works:

```
    Ptr old{*this};
```

Because you have deleted the copy constructor.

```
Ptr(const Ptr&) = delete;
```

If it compiles I am not sure what is happening. But it is definitely not good.

In the constructor you should prefer initializer list.

```
Ptr(T* t, int s = 1) {
    sz = s;              // Initializer list
    p = new T[sz];       // Initializer list.

    // This seems inefficient.
    // Since the line above has just called the constructor on each element
    // element in the array. You are now calling the assignment operator
    // on each element in the array.
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        p[i] = t[i];
    }
}
```

You can optimize the above

```
Ptr(T* t, int s = 1)
    : sz(s)
    , p(reinterpret_cast<T*>(new char[s * sizeof(T)])  // Allocate aligned but uninitialized memory.
{
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        new (p + i) T(t[i]);       // Its called placement new.
                                   // The `(p + i)` is the address where you want the
                                   // construction to take place (ie don't allocate)
                                   // Then we use the copy constructor to create the
                                   // copy
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. a little unrelated, but is there something wrong with the indentation of my code?

Comment: @morbidCode: Indentation looks fine.