# Pointer handle - follow-up

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers

This is a followup to:

- [Pointer class/handle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74774/pointer-class-handle)

Please review this pointer class.

```
template<typename T>
class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr(T* t, int s = 1) {
        sz = s;
        p = new T[sz];
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
            p[i] = t[i];
        }
    }

    Ptr(const Ptr& t) {
        sz = t.sz;
        p = new T[sz];
        T* x = t.get();
        for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
            p[i] = x[i];
        }
    }

    Ptr& operator=(const Ptr& t) {
        Ptr copy{t};
        std::swap(copy.sz, sz);
        std::swap(copy.p, p);
        return *this;
    }

    Ptr(Ptr &&t) :p{t.p}, sz{t.sz} {
        t.p = nullptr;
        t.sz = 0;
    }

    Ptr& operator=(Ptr &&t) {
        std::swap(t.p,p);
        std::swap(t.sz,sz);
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*() {
        check_range();
        return *p;
    }

    T& operator[](int i) {
        check_range(i);
        return p[i];
    }

    T* get() const {
        return p;
    }

    void operator+=(int i) {
        check_range(index+i);
        index += i;
        p+= i;
    }

    void operator-=(int i) {
        check_range(index-i);
        index -= i;
        p -= i;
    }

    Ptr operator+(int i) {
        Ptr old{*this};
        old+=i;
        return old;
    }

    Ptr operator-(int i) {
        Ptr old{*this};
        old-= i;
        return old;
    }

    Ptr& operator++() {
        operator+=(1);
        return *this;
    }

    Ptr operator++(int) {
        Ptr<T> old{p};
        operator++();
        return old;
    }

    Ptr& operator--() {
        operator-=(1);
        return *this;
    }

    Ptr operator--(int) {
        Ptr<T> old{p};
        operator--();
        return old;
    }

    ~Ptr() {
        delete[] p;
    }

private:
    T* p;
    int sz;
    int index = 0;

    void check_range(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > sz-1) {
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        }
    }

    void check_range() {
        if (p == nullptr) {
            throw std::out_of_range("null pointer");
        }
    }

};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

c++11 Allows constructor chaining:

```
Ptr(const Ptr& t) {
    sz = t.sz;
    p = new T[sz];
    T* x = t.get();
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        p[i] = x[i];
    }
}
```

Can be written as:

```
Ptr(const Ptr& t): Ptr(t.p, t.sz) {}
```

Good to see you using the copy and swap idiom.

```
Ptr& operator=(const Ptr& t) {
    Ptr copy{t};
    std::swap(copy.sz, sz);
    std::swap(copy.p, p);
    return *this;
}
```

But his can be simlified by making the compiler to the copy.

```
Ptr& operator=(Ptr copy) {
        //   ^^^^^    Pass by value is generating a copy.       
    std::swap(copy.sz, sz);
    std::swap(copy.p, p);
    return *this;
}
```

This looks good.

```
~Ptr() {
    delete[] p;
}
```

But you ca still move p

```
void operator+=(int i) {
    check_range(index+i);
    index += i;
    p+= i;               // P has changed
}

void operator-=(int i) {
    check_range(index-i);
    index -= i;
    p -= i;               // P has changed
}
```

Thus using it with delete after the point it changed is going to cause UB.

Comment: I still don't understand the dangers on moving p. I've read that delete[] deletes the whole array right? So if I move p anywhere as long as it's within range I thought I can still delete the array. Can you explain further? When will it cause undefined behavior?

Comment: The value passed to `delete` must be the same value that was returned by a call to `new`. So if you change the value of `p` it is not the original value and thus not a valid input to `delete`.

Answer (score 3):

### Operators

You have a bit of duplication with some of the operators:

```
Ptr operator+(int i) {
    Ptr old{*this};
    old+=i;
    return old;
}

Ptr operator-(int i) {
    Ptr old{*this};
    old-= i;
    return old;
}
```

Here we can rewrite the `-` operator in terms of the `+` operator as follows:

```
Ptr operator-(int i) {
    return operator+(-i);
}
```

We can do the same for `-=` and `+=` too. The main benefit here is that we are reducing the amount of duplicated code.

### Constructors

One thing I would do is to use the initializer list to initialize as much as possible in the constructors:

```
Ptr(T* t, int s = 1):
    sz(s<1 ? throw std::logic_error("Invalid size parameter") : s)
{
    p = new T[sz];
    for (int i = 0; i < sz; ++i) {
        p[i] = t[i];
    }
}
```

It would probably be a good idea to check that the size parameter is not negative. When we have a raw array like this we can't easily initialize the array in this manner in the initializer list. If we used a `std::array` as storage this would be a lot easier, though given the [reinventing-the-wheel](/questions/tagged/reinventing-the-wheel) tag that would somewhat defeat the purpose of the question I suppose. This then poses a bit of a design question, you could pass the size of the array in as a template parameter then initialize the space for the array using that template parameter or you can do what you have here.

One other thing you might consider is to use `std::copy` to initialize the array:

```
Ptr(T* t, int s = 1):
    sz(s<1 ? throw std::logic_error("Invalid size parameter") : s)
{
    p = new T[sz];
    std::copy(t, t+sz, p);
}
```

### Bounds checking

```
void check_range(int i) {
    if (i < 0 || i > sz-1) {
        throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
    }
}
```

This doesn't check if `p` is not null, will the operators that call this form of the range check always be presented with a valid pointer?

Comment: Actually, I want to remove the array size as a template parameter. I really want my constructor to just get the size on its own so it'd be easier to use. I just haven't figured out how to do it with raw arrays :)

Comment: Regarding check_range(int i), I thought as long as the element is within range it couldn't be null. But maybe I should check it as well just to make sure.