# Pointer handle - absolute follow-up

Tags: c++, c++11, reinventing-the-wheel, pointers

This is a follow-up to:

- [Pointer handle - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74918/pointer-handle-follow-up)
- [Pointer class/handle](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74774/pointer-class-handle)

Please review my pointer class.

```
template<typename T>
class Ptr {
public:
    Ptr(T* t, int s = 1) : sz{s<1 ? throw std::logic_error("Invalid sz parameter") : s} {
        sz = s;
        p = new T[sz];
        std::copy(t,t+sz,p);
    }

    Ptr(const Ptr& t) : Ptr(t.p, t.sz) { }

    Ptr& operator=(Ptr copy) {
        std::swap(copy.sz, sz);
        std::swap(copy.p, p);
        return *this;
    }

    Ptr(Ptr &&t) :p{t.p}, sz{t.sz} {
        t.p = nullptr;
        t.sz = 0;
    }

    Ptr& operator=(Ptr &&t) {
        std::swap(t.p,p);
        std::swap(t.sz,sz);
        return *this;
    }

    T& operator*() {
        check_range(index);
        return p[index];
    }

    T& operator[](int i) {
        check_range(i);
        return p[i];
    }

    T* get() const {
        return p;
    }

    void operator+=(int i) {
        check_range(index+i);
        index += i;
    }

    void operator-=(int i) {
        operator+=(-i);
    }

    Ptr operator+(int i) {
        Ptr old{*this};
        old += index+i;
        return old;
    }

    Ptr operator-(int i) {
        return operator+(-i);
    }

    Ptr& operator++() {
        operator+=(1);
        return *this;
    }

    Ptr operator++(int) {
        Ptr old{p+index};
        operator++();
        return old;
    }

    Ptr& operator--() {
        operator-=(1);
        return *this;
    }

    Ptr operator--(int) {
        Ptr<T> old{p+index};
        operator--();
        return old;
    }

    ~Ptr() {
        delete[] p;
    }

private:
    T* p;
    int sz;
    int index = 0;

    void check_range(int i) {
        if (i < 0 || i > sz-1) {
            throw std::out_of_range("out of range");
        }
        if (p+i == nullptr) {
            throw std::out_of_range("null pointer");
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: Why did you change the `void operator+=()` to return void rather than a reference. Its not wrong just different from your previous questions.

Comment: @Loki Astari: I temporarily changed them to void while trying to find ways to not move/change p. It's already like that here http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74918/pointer-handle-follow-up. Turned out they're unrelated I forgot to set them back to returning
a reference. There's already an answer here when I found out it's still unchanged :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ptr(T* t, int s = 1): sz{s<1 ? throw std::logic_error("Invalid sz parameter") : s}
{
    sz = s; //this is unnecessary
    p = new T[sz];
    std::copy(t,t+sz,p);
}
```

Here you are writing to `sz` twice, first in the initializer list then in the constructors body. In general it's best if you just write only once in the initializer list if possible:

```
Ptr(T* t, int s = 1):
    sz{s<1 ? throw std::logic_error("Invalid sz parameter") : s}
{
    p = new T[sz];
    std::copy(t,t+sz,p);
}
```

In the move constructor:

```
Ptr(Ptr &&t):
    p{t.p},
    sz{t.sz}
{
    t.p = nullptr;
    t.sz = 0;
}
```

we are changing the pointer and size in this class but not the index. I would "move" everything and take the index from the other class here as well.
We need to set `t.p` to `nullptr` so when `t` gets destructed the the call to `delete[] p;` will be a no-op, so that part is necessary. However I don't see why the `sz` needs to be set to 0 because it's a primitive and therefore not in the destructor. Because the range checking function always checks `p` for a `nullptr` we can't index the old object anyway so I think I would just remove that expression.

```
Ptr(Ptr &&t):
    p{t.p},
    sz{t.sz},
    index{t.index}
{
    t.p = nullptr;
}
```

(Disclaimer: I'm not especially experienced with c++ move semantics so if you think it's more readable to keep explicitly setting every element to a "null" type of value for readability please make a comment, I'd like to know what people think about that.)

Comment: personally I find it good to explicitly set sz to 0 from the point of readability -- but that is just my 2c.

Comment: Setting int to 0 is only for readability :)

Comment: Um, why would we also take index in the move constructor? For example if I am going to return a Ptr from a function, isn't it better if the index of the moved Ptr is at the very beginning of the array?

Comment: @morbidCode, Generally speaking a move constructor moves everything in, so if your move constructor does not do that then it's probably a good spot to add some documentation. Explicitly setting the index back to 0 in the constructor would more clearly state your intention. If the index is not used in that way it would suggest to me that you could remove the `index` from the class entirely. What exactly is your intention with the `index` member?

Comment: In the previous versions of my code, I originally used it to move p whenever functions like operator++ and operator-- executes. Since changing p caused some problems during destruction, now I'm using index to hold p's current index whenever those functions got called without changing p. That's why operator*() returns p[index]. I created it because I can't change sz, I use it for check_range(i) and constructor. Is there a better way of doing this?